# What is the root <layout> element?

Tags: android, android-layout

I noticed that Android Studio auto-completion proposes a `<layout>` element at the root of layout files.

What is its role/meaning?

I tried to use it but it raises a `ClassNotFoundException` exception.

Comment: May I ask the reason for the downvotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<layout>` tag in an Android layout XML file enables the official [Data Binding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) for that layout.

To use it, you must first enable data binding in your build.gradle like so:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

If you are not using data binding, you should remove the `<layout>` tag.